# Putting column value of 2nd row in preceding row once the preceding row is deleted

Tags: sql

I am working on table set_orders.
It has columns order_no and description.
The table has 5 rows.

table looks like this

```
Order_no  Description
-------   -----------
1         cell phone
2         tv
3         camera
4         dvd player
5         music player
```

if order no 3 is deleted then 
the order no column should be updated to

```
Order_no  Description
-------   -----------
1         cell phone
2         tv
3         dvd player
4         music player
```

How should I get the desired result to update the succedding record and arrange the records accordingly.

Comment: Better use another way to order your data. A datetime for instance.

Comment: Requirement is to order the way I have mentioned above. Kindly give some inputs

Answer (score 0):

Changing other records to get a gapless order when one record gets deleted is not the best practice.

What is the order of your data? When it got inserted in the DB? Then use a `datetime` column with a default value like `current_timestamp`. Then you don't have to change anything when a record gets deleted.